# Create Contact Form Without Backend?

Tags: html, forms, email, html-email

I am using a free web host that doesn't support back end code. I am wondering if it is possible to create a contact form without back end support?

I have tried doing the following, but when I submit the form the contents pops open in your email application which defeats the purpose of the form.

```
<FORM ACTION="mailto:you@youraddress.com" METHOD="POST" enctype="text/html">
```

Comment: What did you expect? The browser cannot send emails automagically

Comment: just use [wufoo](http://wufoo.com/signup/#term5), it allows 100 entries per month for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how this functionality works.  It opens your email and puts the content there.  If you want a contact form that doesn't open your email you'll need back end code.  Go to Dreamhost or Bluehost you can get webspace dirt cheap for like $5 a month

Comment: Ahh.. shucks. I was hoping to avoid getting web space as this project is just temporary. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

it is an old post but...

you can use https://formspree.io/, https://app.haboob.co or zapier https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/62/turn-webhooks-into-sent-emails/

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah I probably should have recommended Google Docs form back in 2012, but it didn't really cross my mind...

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a late answer but anyway I post this thinking that someone else will benefit. There are many 3rd party services out there for your exact purpose some of them are free some of them are paid.

Out of all I recommend this service as the service is convenient, the process is straightforward and the good thing is it's **free to use**.

> https://formsubmit.co

Answer (score 2):

Not too late :D

Check this out:

**How to send a web form without code or any backend**

https://dev.to/magarrent-org/how-to-send-a-web-form-without-code-or-any-backend-4lio

[image]

[ActionForms.io](https://www.actionforms.io/)